# javax.persistence.Transient (@Transient) is not working with MongoDB while updating

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, mongo-java, mongo-jackson-mapper, mongojack

I am trying to use **@Transient** (javax.persistence.Transient) in one of my entity, it works fine for inserting the records (the Transient fields are not stored in DB which is OK) but when I am trying to update the same entity the Transient fields also gets stored into mongodb.
I am using Play2.2, mongo-java-driver, MongoJack and MongoDB for my application.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for the actual package like I was, this one will work:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
```

Which is from the [Spring framework API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Transient.html) documentation.

But this one, which is a [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) annotation, will not work for Spring Data's MongoDB:

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
```

Which is part of the [Java Persistence API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonIgnore` (from com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation).